# Logic Apps - Iterate over JSON output from HTTP call

Tags: arrays, json, azure, azure-logic-apps

We are using Azure Logic apps HTTP connector to call a REST service based on the output returned from another REST service in the previous step. The first service is returning a JSON array output as below. The requirement is to loop over the JSON output from Service 1 and construct the URL for service 2 based on the Service 1 output. How do we achieve this in Logic apps ?

```
{
  "totalSize": 32,
  "done": true,
  "records": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFueGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFueGAG",
      "EventType": "ApexCallout",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFueGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 847342
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFufGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFufGAG",
      "EventType": "ApexExecution",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFufGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 9988277
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFugGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFugGAG",
      "EventType": "ApexSoap",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFugGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 54684
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuhGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFuhGAG",
      "EventType": "ApexTrigger",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuhGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 8193546
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuiGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFuiGAG",
      "EventType": "API",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuiGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 14060431
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFujGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFujGAG",
      "EventType": "AsyncReportRun",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFujGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 120591
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFukGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFukGAG",
      "EventType": "BulkApi",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFukGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 34181
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFulGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFulGAG",
      "EventType": "ChangeSetOperation",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFulGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 2088
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFumGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFumGAG",
      "EventType": "ContentDistribution",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFumGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 26642
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFunGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFunGAG",
      "EventType": "ContentDocumentLink",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFunGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 585
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuoGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFuoGAG",
      "EventType": "ContentTransfer",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuoGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 382007
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFupGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFupGAG",
      "EventType": "Dashboard",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFupGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 114791
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuqGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFuqGAG",
      "EventType": "DocumentAttachmentDownloads",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuqGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 1209090
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFurGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFurGAG",
      "EventType": "LightningError",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFurGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 25307
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFusGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFusGAG",
      "EventType": "LightningInteraction",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFusGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 274278
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFutGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFutGAG",
      "EventType": "LightningPageView",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFutGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 26230
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuuGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFuuGAG",
      "EventType": "LightningPerformance",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuuGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 624009
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuvGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFuvGAG",
      "EventType": "LoginAs",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuvGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 28942
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuwGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFuwGAG",
      "EventType": "Login",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuwGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 1295153
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuxGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFuxGAG",
      "EventType": "Logout",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuxGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 123331
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuyGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFuyGAG",
      "EventType": "MetadataApiOperation",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuyGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 69656
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuzGAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFuzGAG",
      "EventType": "QueuedExecution",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFuzGAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 2273083
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv0GAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFv0GAG",
      "EventType": "Report",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv0GAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 54853
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv1GAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFv1GAG",
      "EventType": "ReportExport",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv1GAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 12399
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv2GAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFv2GAG",
      "EventType": "RestApi",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv2GAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 1145345
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv3GAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFv3GAG",
      "EventType": "SearchClick",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv3GAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 47944
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv4GAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFv4GAG",
      "EventType": "Search",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv4GAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 178250
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv5GAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFv5GAG",
      "EventType": "Sites",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv5GAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 1492182
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv6GAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFv6GAG",
      "EventType": "TimeBasedWorkflow",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv6GAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 199635
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv7GAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFv7GAG",
      "EventType": "TransactionSecurity",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv7GAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 3441403
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv8GAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFv8GAG",
      "EventType": "URI",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv8GAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 13043228
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "EventLogFile",
        "url": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv9GAG"
      },
      "Id": "0AT58000002YFv9GAG",
      "EventType": "VisualforceRequest",
      "LogDate": "2018-06-12T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "LogFile": "/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT58000002YFv9GAG/LogFile",
      "LogFileLength": 8839856
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Service1 add an action **parse json**  and Input as an output of previous step(**service1**),This will expose the fields . and then use those field to construct the url and make http call in next step loop will be added automatically.

Comment: create For_Each loop using input as @body('Service1')['rercords'] .

Comment: and then add an http action inside that loop and pass url as @item('For_Each')['attributes']['url']

Comment: +1 for showing me "Parse JSON" is there.  But on a sidenote, that is now buried within the "Operations" action.